# Is there a way to change the Storybook story width (ie. storybook-root) selectively?

Tags: storybook

I'm trying to see if there's a way to change the width for select stories. My component is 100% width which I don't want to change because it is 100% of the parent. For Storybook that would be where `id="storybook-root` lives. The first screenshots below shows what it looks like by default. I would like to set the width to something like 500px (2nd screenshot).

I understand I can [create a html page](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-rendering) and add styling within there but that would apply to all stories. I want to be able to update the width for select stories.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The storybook `layout` parameter can accept 3 different values namely `centered`, `fullscreen`, or, `padded`, where `padded` is the default. In the 2nd screenshot shared in the question above the css selector for `storybook-root` contains `.sb-show-main.sb-main-centered` which infers that the story layout is set to `centered`. It can be changed to either `fullscreen`, or `padded`. Also ref. https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-layout

```
const meta = {
  title: "Title/ComponentName",
  component: ComponentName,
  parameters: {
    layout: "fullscreen", // or `padded` by default
  },
};
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not currently working in Storybook atm but will nevertheless accept your answer. Hopefully this does the trick.